# Надо синонимизировать [сеттеры]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо синонимизировать метки

- [сеттеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b) (10 вопросов)
- [setter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setter) (38 вопросов)

Какую сделать главной - вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объединил в сторону [setter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setter), она имеет описание и более используемая.

```
updating post history, 10 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 10 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 10 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'сеттеры': [сеттеры] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 48
tag remapping of [setter] and [сеттеры] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym сеттеры -> setter was approved!
```